# How to add less than or equal to condition in linq inner join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

We have two objects, `Dates` and `ActiveEvents`. Want to perform inner join on these with less than or equal to condition in linq. Same as ref of below SQL where consider `#Tables` are C# objects

```
Select A. from #Activities A
Inner Join #Dates D ON A.ActivityDate <= D.ProcessDate
```

Tried with below but it's not giving correct results.

```
 var filteredActivity = (from e in ActiveEvents
            from p in dates
            where e.ActivityDate <= p.Date
            select new ActiveEvent
            {
                ActivityDate = p.Date,
                EventId = e.EventId
            }).ToList();
```

And

```
  var filteredActivity = (from e in ActiveEvents
            from p in dates.Where(r => e.ActivityDate <= r)
            select new ActiveEvent
            {
                ActivityDate = p.Date,
                EventId = e.EventId
            }).ToList();
```

Can you please suggest any better way to do this?

Comment: Where is the Join?

Comment: Your SQL should be equivalent to `Select * From Activities A, Dates D Where A.ActivityDate <= D.ProcessDate`, so that first Linq query should do what you want.  How exactly is it giving wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way

```
var filteredActivity = (from e in ActiveEvents
        join p in dates
        where e.ActivityDate <= p.ProcessDate 
        select new ActiveEvent
        {
            ActivityDate = p.Date,
            EventId = e.EventId
        }).ToList();
```

P/s: Ideally, between 2 tables should contain the `foreign key` to join like this `join p in dates on e.Key equals p.ForeignKey`

Answer (score -2):

Based on your example, the query is filtering on `ProcessDate` but your linq query is filtering on `p.Date`.  Are those the same field?  The first example you gave should be correct.

Comment: This would be better as a comment since you're asking for clarification.  And if this is the case then the question should be closed as a typo.